# Не получается убрать /ru/ в урле

Tags: url, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, уже все перепробовал...

Как правильно прописать в `.haccess`, чтобы при переходе на по ссылке или впри вводе в строку адреса http://advocate.kr.ua/ru/ шел редирект на http://advocate.kr.ua без /ru/

сейчас так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^advocate.kr.ua$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ru/(.+)$ http://advocate.kr.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

спасибо!

Comment: @dakamuza, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Вас должно смутить, что:  

    RewriteEngine On
находится после:  

    RewriteCond
А также то, что  

    RewriteCond 
В третьей строке запрещает применение правила на желаемом домене. Нужно убрать восклицательный знак.

Comment: спасибо!

ошибки конечно есть, не спорю... в пхп не шарю, и с .htaccess сталкиваюсь впервые...

короче нашел где-то совет про редирект и поставил такую строку в самом конце файла

RedirectPermanent /ru/ http://www.advocate.kr.ua/ua/

помогло)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/ru\/$ $1
```

не проверял, но примерно так.